# Remove null elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm troubling about deleting the unused/empty elements, here is my code:

```
  public GameObject[] ActivateTrayQuest;;
  public GameObject[] countersForEverybody;


void Start(){
    ActivateTrayQuest = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ActivateTrayQuest");
    foreach (GameObject remain in ActivateTrayQuest) 
    {
        if(ActivateTrayQuest[0] == null && ActivateTrayQuest[1] == null && ActivateTrayQuest[2] == null){
            Array.Resize (ref ActivateTrayQuest, 0);
        }
    }

    ActivateTrayQuest[0] = ActivateTrayQuest [ActivateTrayQuest.Length - 1];
    ActivateTrayQuest[1] = ActivateTrayQuest [ActivateTrayQuest.Length - 2];
    ActivateTrayQuest[2] = ActivateTrayQuest [ActivateTrayQuest.Length - 3];
```

I mean by deleting is that like resizing my array.

[image: Elements that are unused]

I want to delete the Element 0, 1, 2
so that it'll be more like 0,1,2 again .
how can i obtain this?

Comment: If `GameObject` `Destroy()`d, `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` will not contain destroyed object, so there will be no `ActiveTrayQuest[0] == null`

Comment: so what should i do then sir

Comment: Your question is unclear, explain how objects became null maybe?

Comment: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/serializehelper-free-save-and-load-utility-de-serialize-all-objects-in-your-scene.338148/

It is because of this saving and loading system sir. All of my objects in my current scene are going to be overwritten and change all of my objects into the objects the objects in my prefab folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the right answer for the problem, but to literally remove the `null` elements from an array, simply do this:

```
ActivateTrayQuest = ActivateTrayQuest.Where(x=>x != null).ToArray();
```

You'll also need `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Comment: @TheGinxx009 - Then you need to be clearer about what you need.

Comment: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/serializehelper-free-save-and-load-utility-de-serialize-all-objects-in-your-scene.338148/
 It is because of this saving and loading system sir. All of my objects in my current scene are going to be overwritten and change all of my objects into the objects the objects in my prefab folder

Comment: @TheGinxx009 - OK. So where is the problem?

Comment: U have quite made it complex @TheGinxx009

Comment: @utkub hahaha im really sorry sir about that.